# Full text contains with a column from another table

Tags: sql-server, contains, cross-apply

I need to search for a text that is larger than 4000 characters.

This is the select I tried to do instead of putting a very long string in the contains:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT code 
    FROM table_a
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT * 
     FROM table_b
     WHERE CONTAINS(table_b.field, cte.code)) c
```

but this approach didn't work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: *"but this solution wouldn't work."* Why wouldn't it? How do you know if you haven't tried?

Comment: because contains did not work to me when i put a field from another table. it worked only with a string or a variable.

Answer (score 0):

A cursor can solve the problem, but you should be aware of implications to performance, depending on your data.

In more details: Have a cursor loop through table_a. For each loop, set a variable to the code. Use that code as the argument to the CONTAINS function. If there is a match, insert the values of the code and table_b.id in a temporary table. After all the looping, you have the results in the temporary table.